# How can i make my UITableViewCell contain two labels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I want my UITableViewCell to look like the image below where there seems to be two labels. Is this possible without subclassing UITableViewCell?

[alt text http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2764/photoobp.jpg](http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/2764/photoobp.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different styles of UITableVieWCell. See here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/cellstyle

I think you want to use UITableViewCellStyleValue1.

You can initialise your UITableViewCell with the relevant style:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623276-init

When you use a style that has two labels, you can use the textLabel and detailTextLabel properties to set them, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to subclass a `UITableViewCell` in order to add content to it.  Here could be a sample cell generation method with an extra label:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.textLabel.frame];
        secondLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        secondLabel.tag = 12345;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];
    }

    UILabel *second = [cell viewWithTag:12345];
    second.text = @"Second!";

    return cell;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.  I can clarify some things if needed.

Comment: While adding subviews to the cell's `contentView` is powerful and useful, this extra work is unnecessary for answering the specific question. See the table view cell styles for examples of cells which match the asker's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where u think you see 2 labels...you can set the UILabels number of lines property if you want more lines [UILabel ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/numberOfLines)....Also there is a UITableViewCell type  UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
 which contains a detailTextLabel on top of the regular text labels in UITableCell, so you already have a built in cell with 2 text fields, here is a ref [ref to UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellStyle)

Answer (score 0):

Its not 2 labels but 2 buttons, you need to add 2 buttons in contentView view of the cell. Or you can create a footer or header View and add these 2 buttons.